# How to list (compile time introspection) all the class/struct methods in D?

Tags: d, introspection

How to list all methods (template and plain) of the class or struct in D? Compile time.

Comment: You may find some clues here: http://www.ddili.org/ders/d.en/uda.html

Answer (score 2):

`__traits(allMembers)`

http://dlang.org/spec/traits.html#allMembers

The sample chapter of my book goes into more detail too: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/d-cookbook

you use allMembers to get the names, getOverloads to get overloads, and the other traits to identify just what they all are.

Comment: Again =) How do I list all the methods? allMembers returns everything: fields, methods, virtual methods, templates, template methods... Currently I am able to detect just non-template methods (through MemberFunctionsTuple emptiness or fullness). But I can't distinguish between templates and template methods. I do not see the "isMethod" in the traits list.

Comment: Ok, I see in your book, getMember with "is(typeof(member) == function))" do the stuff. I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, that plus the `__traits(getOverloads)` can get them all. Templates are bit trickier because they aren't actually functions until instantiated though...

Comment: is(typeof(member) == function)) will be false for a template function?

Comment: It can be if you don't give it arguments there. For example, std.conv.to is NOT a function, but std.conv.to!int IS.